# Do all the numbers belong to same slot in the Hashtable?

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics, mathematical-programming

I was reading the CLRS. In the Hashing Chapter on page 262 a statement says: "For example, if we know that the
keys are random real numbers $k$ independently and uniformly distributed in the range $0 \leq k < 1$, then the hash function $h(k)= \lfloor km \rfloor$."

Question: Does Uniformly distributed meant all numbers have equal probability.
if so then all numbers have the same $k$ values and belong to the same slot.

Comment: They have the same $k$ with zero probability.

Answer (score 1):

Keys are uniformly distributed means that they are drawn from a space with equal probability.

So if we set the hash function to be $h(k)=\lfloor{km}\rfloor$, then each given element is equally likely to hash into any of the $m$ slots. (Refer to the definition of simple uniform hashing in page 259 CLRS)

Yes, it is true that each element with key $k$ will be hashed to the same slot. But the point is the elements are chosen uniformly independently, so they have the same probability to hash to any of the $m$ slots.

Comment: 'Uniformly distributed in the range 0 <= k < 1'
Here k talks about the probability of each element to hash or something else.
Thanks

Comment: Well I think it talks about the key values. The keys are chosen uniformly in the interval [0, 1]. So the prob of it being any value in this interval is equal.

Comment: Snjor, your argument means that a dice always shows the same number when you throw it. That’s not my experience.

Comment: @bmchaitu In reference to your first comment above, $k$ doesn't have anything to do with probability. It is simply a real number in the interval $[0, 1)$. Probability comes in only when you decide that each value $k$ is as likely as any other.

Answer (score 1):

Your conclusion "then all numbers have the same $k$ values" is not justified. The samples are anywhere in $[0,1)$ and can fall in any slot.

Uniformly means that in the long run, all slots will be filled in a balanced way. (The $\text{pdf}$ of $k$ is continuous and constant. The expectation of the filling of any bin is $\dfrac nb$ for $n$ drawings and $b$ bins. In other words, the probability to fall in a given bin is $\dfrac1b$.)